# Simple Cox-related question regarding the LR test

Tags: statistical-significance, cox-model, likelihood-ratio

I'm writing the Results section of a paper: If the LR-test for a Cox proportional hazards model is **not** significant, but one of the predictors *is* significant, does one (usually) report the covariate's significance and sign?

Or does an insignificant LR test result mean that one skips discussing the significance of any regressors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've asked the question in a somewhat vague manner, so I'm going to answer what I believe to be your intended question.

Question I think you're asking: suppose we use a LR test on the full model, and find insignificance, yet one of our covariates, when tested individually, is found to be significant. Should we report the individually significant result?

The answer is: it depends on what your question is. Even my reforming of the question was a little vague.

If your study question, *a priori*, was "does specific covariate X affect Y, given Z1, Z2, ...," then the real statistical test of interest in on X, and only X, not Z1, Z2, etc., as these were variables you wanted to adjust for, but you were not concerned with testing their relation with Y. In that case, that one hypotheses test on X is all you really cared about, and so that individual test, not the LR test, should be what is reported. I will say that if this is what you had in mind and your LR-test was insignificant, that would actually be very strange: it would imply that all these Z1, Z2's had almost no effect, so much so that it drowned out the effect X in the LR test. But you should have been including them in your model because you thought they did have an effect. So that would be odd (enough so to warrant double checking things).

The other possibility, which I think is more likely, is that you were interested in testing *several* hypotheses at once; you tested X1, X2, etc, and you were interested in whether any of these were significant. You noticed that the LR-test for the full model was not significant, but the covariate X2, for example, was significant. This should *not* be reported as statistically significant; I'm brushing over things, but essentially you should think that this is due to multiple comparisons.

Comment: Apologies for being vague -- I was trying to be simple and clear :) This is an exploratory study seeking to assess the impact of various covariates on the development of power projects (not a standard use for survival analysis, I know). All I'd like to know is: when writing the results, should I report the significance of a covariate in a model that does not pass the LR test?

Comment: Unless the role of the particular covariate in question was a specific pre-planned test, you should not state that the covariate has a statistically significant relation to survival, as already noted in this answer. As this is an exploratory study, you certainly can report the specific results you obtained so that you and your colleagues can discuss the advisability of further study. But don't call them "significant" statistically.

Comment: To be clear, I didn't mean you were being "vague" to attack your question, but just to point out that there were different ways to interpret your question, and I was choosing this way. I think it's a great question to help clarify common situations analysts face.